# gnuplot: Why a Background Image Affects the Plotting of Data Points

Tags: gnuplot

The position of plotted data points is different if I use a background image or not, let me explain:

If I generate a chart (One.png) using this script without a background image:

```
$DATA<<EOD
1.0000,"2.0 Years\n10.0",277.5000,249.1100
2.0000,"3.0 Years\n11.0",345.4167,312.1800
3.0000,"4.0 Years\n12.0",413.3333,375.2500
4.0000,"5.0 Years\n13.0",481.2500,438.3200
5.0000,"6.0 Years\n14.0",549.1667,501.3900
6.0000,"7.0 Years\n15.0",617.0833,564.4600
7.0000,"8.0 Years\n16.0",685.0000,627.5300
8.0000,"9.0 Years\n17.0",752.9167,690.6000
9.0000,"10.0 Years\n18.0",820.8333,753.6700
10.0000,"11.0 Years\n19.0",888.7500,816.7400
11.0000,"12.0 Years\n20.0",956.6667,879.8100
12.0000,"13.0 Years\n21.0",1024.5833,942.8800
13.0000,"14.0 Years\n22.0",1092.5000,1005.9500
14.0000,"15.0 Years\n23.0",1160.4167,1069.0200
15.0000,"16.0 Years\n33.0",1228.3333,1699.7200
16.0000,"17.0 Years\n34.0",1296.2500,1762.7900
17.0000,"18.0 Years\n35.0",1364.1667,1825.8600
18.0000,"19.0 Years\n36.0",1432.0833,1888.9300
19.0000,"20.0 Years\n37.0",1500.0000,1952.0000
EOD
set datafile separator comma
set style data point
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 1700,2200
set output 'C:\temp\One.png'
unset xtics; unset ytics; unset x2tics; unset y2tics
set grid noxtics
set grid noytics
set border 0
set colorsequence classic
set key off
set xrange [0:1699]
set yrange [0:2199]
set label 01 "This is the name" at 1136.00,2050.00 font "Tahoma,20" left front textcolor rgb "black"
set label 02 "Record No." at 1409.90,2007.00 font "Tahoma,20" left front textcolor rgb "black"
plot $DATA using ($3):($4) with points pt 1 ps 4 lc rgb "0xE25822" lw 3 notitle
```

The resulting chart looks great: [image: No background]

Now, If I use One.png as my background image and generate a chart with the same script\data points:

```
$DATA<<EOD
1.0000,"2.0 Years\n10.0",277.5000,249.1100
2.0000,"3.0 Years\n11.0",345.4167,312.1800
3.0000,"4.0 Years\n12.0",413.3333,375.2500
4.0000,"5.0 Years\n13.0",481.2500,438.3200
5.0000,"6.0 Years\n14.0",549.1667,501.3900
6.0000,"7.0 Years\n15.0",617.0833,564.4600
7.0000,"8.0 Years\n16.0",685.0000,627.5300
8.0000,"9.0 Years\n17.0",752.9167,690.6000
9.0000,"10.0 Years\n18.0",820.8333,753.6700
10.0000,"11.0 Years\n19.0",888.7500,816.7400
11.0000,"12.0 Years\n20.0",956.6667,879.8100
12.0000,"13.0 Years\n21.0",1024.5833,942.8800
13.0000,"14.0 Years\n22.0",1092.5000,1005.9500
14.0000,"15.0 Years\n23.0",1160.4167,1069.0200
15.0000,"16.0 Years\n33.0",1228.3333,1699.7200
16.0000,"17.0 Years\n34.0",1296.2500,1762.7900
17.0000,"18.0 Years\n35.0",1364.1667,1825.8600
18.0000,"19.0 Years\n36.0",1432.0833,1888.9300
19.0000,"20.0 Years\n37.0",1500.0000,1952.0000
EOD
set datafile separator comma
set style data point
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 1700,2200
set output 'C:\temp\Two.png'
unset xtics; unset ytics; unset x2tics; unset y2tics
set grid noxtics
set grid noytics
set border 0
set colorsequence classic
set key off
set xrange [0:1699]
set yrange [0:2199]
set label 01 "This is the name" at 1136.00,2050.00 font "Tahoma,20" left front textcolor rgb "black"
set label 02 "Record No." at 1409.90,2007.00 font "Tahoma,20" left front textcolor rgb "black"
plot 'C:\temp\One.png' binary filetype=PNG w rgbimage,\
$DATA using ($3):($4) with points pt 1 ps 4 lc rgb "0xE25822" lw 3 notitle
```

The resulting Two.png image shows the data points not in the same place as One.png, they are being "pulled" towards the center of the image:
[image: With Background]

Why having a background image (or not) affects the position of the data points? and how can this be prevented?

Thank you,
Roberto

Comment: You really want an PNG image aligned with a plot, correct? You are not looking for plotting multiple curves into one graph or `set multiplot`? Check the margins. If your margins are not zero, the image will be squeezed into the second graph area.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Setting the l\r\t\bmargin to 0 worked perfectly. I will include these settings for this point forward.

Thank you so very much.
Roberto

Comment: glad to hear. But I still don't fully understand why you are not using `multiplot`? Maybe the real question or goal is still hidden? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the StackOverflow rule: "no answers in comments",
let me put this into an answer:

Set your margins to zero:

```
set margins 0,0,0,0
```

This works fine if you don't need margins and axes labels. However, I still don't fully understand your final goal. Why are you not using `set multiplot` to overlay two plots?

However, if you want put a given background image into a graph (without using `multiplot`), but *with* axes labels and *defined* coordinates, I haven't found yet a satisfying solution. Maybe I will post it as question.